# How to Configure WebSocket Server to Accept Secure Connection Request

Tags: laravel-5, websocket, ratchet

Before applying ssl(I take from cloudflare) my website is loaded over http and my socket connection is made over ws
and it's working fine and connection was made successfully.

> conn = new WebSocket('ws://myDomain:8090');

But after applying ssl when my website loads over https the I use wss (otherwise it give error)

> conn = new WebSocket('wss://myDomain:8090');

Now it gives me the error

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://myDomain:8090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

The websocket server is started over 8090 port I also change the port to 9991 but to no avail.

Here is the code for websocket server

```
public function handle()
{
    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new WebSocketController()
            )
        ),
        8090
    );
    $server->run();
}
```

**I don't configure apache to to run a websocket server to accept secure connection request.** May be due to this I am getting an error. It means that I am sending a secure connection request to an insecure websocket server. If I am right can you tell me how I configure my websocket server so that it can accept secure connection request.

**I am again telling you that I am  using the SSL from cloud flare.** I tell me my domain and they provide me nameservers to replace it with my existing nameservers.

I requested you to give a clear solution to solve this. **I am not using nginx, I am using apache on Lampp.**

Comment: What does your nginx config look like? Are you sure that you are serving over a secure connection?

Comment: I don't install nginx, I am using apache on Lampp.

Comment: OK...you mentioned nginx in your question, so I thought you were using it. How have you configured apache to accept secure websocket connections?

Comment: I don't make any configurations. I think my websocket server is only able to accept insecure websocket connection . Can you tell me how to make these configurations so that my websocket server can accept secure connections.

Comment: Review the edited question. You can view more info after the code snippest. See last three paragraphs.

Comment: @habib did you found any solution? i have  the same problem, also using cloudflare

Comment: Not, till now. Provide me your mail or anykind of info so that I will contact you if I will find a solution.

Comment: @adam west, I had found a solution. You can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone solved my problem. So I am posting the solution here to help others. I was making two mistakes.

- I am using SSL from cloudflare, which causes some issues. So I buy a paid SSL certificate.
- I don't configure my websocket server for wss

So here is the code to configure your websocket server for wss in Laravel with Ratchet

```
public function handle()
{

    $loop   = Factory::create();
    $webSock = new SecureServer(
        new Server('0.0.0.0:8090', $loop),
        $loop,
        array(
            'local_cert'        => '', // path to your cert
            'local_pk'          => '', // path to your server private key
            'allow_self_signed' => TRUE, // Allow self signed certs (should be false 
                                            in production)
            'verify_peer' => FALSE
        )
    );
    // Ratchet magic
    $webServer = new IoServer(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new WebSocketController()
            )
        ),
        $webSock
    );
    $loop->run();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare doesn't work with port `8090`, [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-) is the list of the ports that are supported by cloudflare.

Also try `http://sitemeer.com/#https://yourDomain:8090` to see if your server + domain is serving ssl